# awk print overwrite strings

Tags: awk, printing, overwrite

I have a problem using awk in the terminal.
I need to move many files in a group from the actual directory to another one and I have the list of the necessary files in a text file, as:

filename.txt

```
file1
file2
file3
...
```

I usually digit:

```
paste filename.txt | awk '{print "mv "$1" ../dir/"}' | sh
```

and it executes:

```
mv file1 ../dir/
mv file2 ../dir/
mv file3 ../dir/
```

It usually works, but now the command changes its behaviour and awk overwrites the last string `../dir/` on the first one, starting again the print command from the initial position, obtaining:

```
../dire1 ../dir/
../dire2 ../dir/
../dire3 ../dir/
```

and of course it cannot be executed.
What's happened?
How do I solve it?

Comment: BTW, the `awk | sh` practice shown here runs serious security risks. If managing an anonymous FTP site or any other scenario where you don't have complete control of your filenames, you **really** don't want to use this code to manage one that's named `$(rm -rf ~).txt`. (One major dataloss incident at a former employer was caused by a bug in a C module used by a Python program dumping random memory into a buffer that was only *supposed* to contain hex digits; it doesn't require malicious intent for Bad Things to happen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input file contains carriage returns (`\r` aka `control-M`). Run `dos2unix` on it before running a UNIX tool on it.

idk what you're using paste for though, and you should not be using awk for this at all anyway, it's just a job for a simple shell script, e.g. remove the `echo` once you've tested this:

```
$ < file xargs -n 1 -I {} echo mv "{}" "../dir"
mv file1 ../dir
mv file2 ../dir
mv file3 ../dir
```

Comment: If on a GNU platform, `xargs -d $'\n' mv -t ../dir -- <file` avoids the need to generate and run shell commands, and is **far** safer in the presence of malicious or uncontrolled filenames (well, those names still can't contain literal newlines, but that's better than executing embedded shell commands they contain).

Comment: ...frankly, I think it's an overwhelmingly strong case that `awk` is just plain the wrong tool for this job. If you want to generate shell commands safely, you need a quoting/escaping method; with bash or ksh, you have `printf %q`; with awk, you've got nothing.